# Linear Kalman filter with partially hidden variable

Tags: inference, kalman-filter

If I have a hidden underlying state variable called x and a measurement variable called z, the linear Kalman filter allows me to update the predictions recursively as new measurements come in. If the hidden state variable is occasionally exposed (say for 30% of the measurements) of the measurements, what is the best way to handle this data? Do I do regression on the dataset where x is exposed and somehow use that to improve my prediction when x is hidden?

If I start from a purely Bayesian first principles viewpoint, it seems logical to reset the Kalman filter every time one gets an exposed x since the actual underlying state is known. Is that the right way to think about it?

Comment: Add to the question: what if the state is always exposed?

Comment: I think by "exposed" you mean "perfect measurement" - one with no noise? 
Also, do you mean there is just a single state variable x, and a single measurement z, in which case z = h(x) + noise, and in which case we could transform z as well so really just consider z = x + noise for the sake of argument. In that case, it's not clear what "hidden" means. Or did you mean that these variables are part of a larger set of states and measurements?)  In which case, we have an occasional second "perfect measurement".  Are we just replacing the noisy measurement with the perfect one in that time step?